# Monitor Exchange bandwidth by user / mailbox

Tags: exchange, monitoring, bandwidth, bandwidth-measuring

We share an exchange servers between 5 different companies. Our exchange server is consuming a massive amount of bandwidth every month (up to almost a TB!). It's hosted offsite and our hosting provider charges a pretty penny for bandwidth usage.

So, I need to be able to monitor which user/mailbox is taking the most bandwidth in order to re-bill the extra bandwidth charges to each company.

I'm looking at ExMon ([Exchange monitor](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2003/tools/Microsoft-Exchange-Server-User-Monitor.html)) right now, and it *does* tell me the info I need, but it's an instantaneous measurement and, as far as I know, there is no way to aggregate all those instant measurements over a month to get an overview of who's creating all that Exchange bandwidth.

A quick google didn't help me find any free Exchange bandwidth reporting/monitoring software. Perfmon doesn't help me either as I can't find the proper metrics in there.

Does anyone have any idea what tools I could use?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion makes use of the message tracking logs, so it can only query as far back as your message tracking logs go. That said, if you run this script on a weekly/monthly basis, you will be able to track who is sending the most/biggest mail. 
Be sure to modify the 'start' and 'end' times in the script, as well as your preferred directory for the csv that is exported. powershell script below:

```
$x=Get-TransportServer

$x | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start "01/14/2014 12:00AM" -End "01/15/2014 12:00AM" -EventId "DELIVER" -ResultSize Unlimited |select-object Sender,@{Name="Recipients";Expression={$_.recipients}},MessageSubject,MessageId,Timestamp,TotalBytes,EventId | export-csv C:\outputdirectory\output_stats.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, charging them for bandwidth might be a great way to push them to migrate to Office365. Which honestly might be the best solution for them, but doesn't help you out much, unless you are or become an MS partner and work with them to get the referral to do the migration.